# How to handle questions posted on S.O. and then on EE S.E

Tags: discussion

Whenever I see a strictly-EE-question posted on StackOverflow I suggest that the asker repost it here in our EE beta SE.

For example today [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22235/expressionengine-404-not-found-index-php-products-was-not-found#22237) sat ignored for two hours in SO but was answered in 12 minutes when [duplicated in EE SE](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22235/expressionengine-404-not-found-index-php-products-was-not-found#22237).

Great that the asker gets a quicker answer, but now we have needless duplicate content.

When I see posts like this what is the best way to handle, should I:

1. Ask the submitter to ask a new question and to delete their old one?
2. Ask the submitter to request that a moderator move their question?
3. Ask the submitter to add a link to their new question?
4. Myself ask that a moderator move the question?

Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that #4 is your best bet - flag it on Stack Overflow and add a note indicating that it should be moved to ExpressionEngine Answers - it will likely be dealt with pretty quickly.

Comment: I agree #4 is the best option. Here's a screencast of where/how to flag. In the textarea, type something like "Question is a better fit for http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com"

Comment: See no screencast but I know how to flag.  I've never had a post moved by a moderator.  Is it a decent experience for the asker?

Comment: This is generally the best option.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl FYI I'm finding that about half of my migration requests are declined "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Comment: @AllInOne I only see 2 flags for you on the main EE site and they were marked as "helpful". On which site are you flagging questions for migration?

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl the denied flags were on SO.  Two are still open: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537395/expressionengine-variable-not-parsed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292350/getting-child-category-data-from-parent-category-in-expressionengine and one has since been closed.

Comment: I can't say why they are getting declined. Have you asked those moderators?